# Two points in $z,w \in \mathbb C$ with same distance to three other points

Tags: complex-analysis, geometry, euclidean-geometry

Suppose that $a,b,c \in \mathbb C$ are three complex numbers which do not lie on a line. Further, let $z,w \in \mathbb C$ are such that
$$
|z-a|=|w-a|, \ \ |z-b|=|w-b|, \ \ |z-c|=|w-c| .
$$
Is it true that $z=w$? Intuitively I would say yes due to geometric considerations but I would like to have a formal proof of it.

Comment: Three non-linear points define a unique circle, the circumcircle of the associated triangle.  The center of this circle, the circumcenter, is the intersection of the three perpendicular bisectors.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $z\neq w$. Then there is a unique line $l$ of finite length in the complex plane that connects the points $z$ and $w$.

$|z-a|=|w-a|$ implies that point $a$ lies on the unique [perpendicular bisector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection#Line_segment_bisector) $l^\perp$ of the line $l$. (Exercise)

By the same argument, also $b$ and $c$ lie on this line $l^\perp$.

Thus, $a$, $b$ and $c$ are collinear.

Thus, we have proven: "$a$, $b$ and $c$ do not lie on the same line $\implies z=w$." You are correct with your intuition.

Comment: This. The initial condition turns out to be the most crucial and important one.